# Why does an operator on smooth functions vanishing at $p$ have a unique extension to a derivation?

Tags: differential-geometry

On page 78 of Spivak's Differential Geometry, he mentions that a linear operator $\ell$ on all $C^\infty$ functions is a derivation at $p$ when satisfying
$$
\ell(fg)=f(p)\ell(g)+g(p)\ell(f).
$$

Later, suppose $\mathscr{F}_p$ is the set of all $C^\infty$ functions $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(p)=0$. Let $\ell\colon\mathscr{F}_p\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear operator with $\ell(fg)=0$ for all $f,g\in\mathscr{F}_p$.

Why does $\ell$ have a unique extension to a derivation? The condition is certainly necessary. Just to get started, I assumed $\hat{\ell}$ is an extension. I took $h$ to be any smooth function, and if $\hat{\ell}$ is to be a derivation,
$$
\hat{\ell}(hf)=f(p)\hat{\ell}(h)+h(p)\hat{\ell}(f)=h(p)\ell(f)
$$
but hit a dead end after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Given any smooth function $h$, consider $f=h-h(p) \in\mathscr F_p$. What must a derivation do to constant functions?

Comment: Thanks Ted. Derivations must send constant functions to $0$. So if $\hat{\ell}$ were an extension, then $0=\hat{\ell}(f)=\hat{\ell}(h)-\hat{\ell}(h(p))=\hat{\ell}(h)$? So the only possible extension is the zero derivation?

Comment: No, no! Why the $0$ at the left here? You should get $\tilde\ell(h)=\ell(f)$. Now check this is a derivation!

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Thanks for the hint.